# How to join multiple headers in Apache Camel Aggregator correlation

Tags: apache-camel

I want to read multiple headers in camel aggregator. Something like this - header("h1") and header("h2"). Is this possible?

```
from(sourceQueueUrl)
    .aggregate(header("h1") and header("h2")  , new MyAggregationStrategy())
    .completionSize(3)
    .closeCorrelationKeyOnCompletion(2000)
    .log("Sending out ${body}")
    .aggregationRepository(repository)
    .to(sinkQueueUrl);
```

Comment: Got it working now! header("h1").append(header("h2")) works fine.

Comment: You should post it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working now! `header("h1").append(header("h2"))` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use the `simple` expression language like this:

```
from(sourceQueueUrl)
    .aggregate(simple("${header.h1}+${header.h2}"))
    .aggregationStrategy(new MyAggregationStrategy())
    .completionSize(3)
    .closeCorrelationKeyOnCompletion(2000)
    .log("Sending out ${body}")
    .aggregationRepository(repository)
    .to(sinkQueueUrl);
```

This is equivalent to your solution but I personally find the syntax simpler and easier to understand.
Also putting the `aggregationStrategy` on a separate line make it also more readable.